# Is there a Javascript event that is trigger when an iOS user chooses an <option> in a <select?>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax

I have three hierarchical `<select>` menus in a web app. The first two have onchange event handlers that fire some ajax that reduces the options in the successive `<select>`'s.

However, it doesn't seem that the onchange handler fires until the user presses the next field button ">". However, once this is done, they are already placed into the second `<select>` which still shows the original set of `<options>`. The only way to get the AJAX populated options is to go to the previous field and back again, or blur and focus the field.

Is there another event that I can attach to, so that once the iOS user chooses the option in the `<select>` control, the AJAX can immediately fire?

Comment: [You may find this article useful](http://www.citytechinc.com/us/en/blog/2014/02/resetting-the-value-of-select-boxes-in-safari-for-ios.html).

Comment: @jaydisc  share your demo code